# Large list of parameters in javascript constructors

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance

My coach in the comments told me that here's large list of parameters, what did he mean?

```
function Product(id, name, cost, quantity, shortDescription, fullDescription) {
      this.id = id;
      this.name = name;
      this.cost = cost;
      this.quantity = quantity;
      this.shortDescription = shortDescription;
      this.fullDescription = fullDescription;
    }
```

Comment: It's part of my challenge but I don't know what to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `id`, `name`, `cost`, `quantity`, `shortDescription`, and `fullDescription` are *parameters* (you'll frequently hear them called "arguments"<sup>1</sup>) to the `Product` function. He's saying six is too many. It's a matter of style and maintenance, and opinions may vary, but that's what he's saying.

You might consider using a single `options` parameter instead:

```
function Product(options) {
    this.id = options.id;
    this.name = options.name;
    this.cost = options.cost;
    this.quantity = options.quantity;
    this.shortDescription = options.shortDescription;
    this.fullDescription = options.fullDescription;
}
```

...which you would call by passing in an object with those properties on it, like this:

```
var p = new Person({
    id: 42,
    name: "Douglas Adams",
    cost: "Priceless",
    quantity: 0,
    shortDescription: "Great author",
    fullDescription: "Mostly harmless"
});
```

In ES2015 and higher, you can do that with *destructuring* parameters:

```
function Product({id, name, cost, quantity, shortDescription, fullDescription}) {
    // Note -----^-----------------------------------------------------------^
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.cost = cost;
    this.quantity = quantity;
    this.shortDescription = shortDescription;
    this.fullDescription = fullDescription;
}
```

You still *call* it the same way, with an object:

```
let p = new Person({
    id: 42,
    name: "Douglas Adams",
    cost: "Priceless",
    quantity: 0,
    shortDescription: "Great author",
    fullDescription: "Mostly harmless"
});
```

Again: That's ES2015 and above.

---

<sup>1</sup> *parameters* vs. *arguments*: In the declaration, the technically-correct term is "parameter." In the *call*, the term is "argument". E.g., here's a function taking a `name` *parameter*:

```
function foo(name) {
    // ...
}
```

...and here we are calling it with the *argument* "Douglas":

```
foo("Douglas");
```

In everyday speech, it's absolutely fine to talk about "the `name` argument" without making the parameter/argument distinction. But that's the distinction: The abstract thing in the declaration vs. the concrete thing in the call.